# Unable to detect update using the flutter package "upgrader"

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and since I want the user to be automatically be notified if there is an update/force them to update, I used the flutter package upgrader(https://github.com/larryaasen/upgrader). The debug shows that there are no available updates even though my pubspec version is lower than the minimum app version that I set in the dart and XML.

dart:

```
final appcastURL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeejaykim/apispa/jeejaykim-test/test.xml';
final cfg = AppcastConfiguration(url: appcastURL, supportedOS: ['android']);

return Scaffold(
        body: UpgradeAlert(
            dialogStyle: UpgradeDialogStyle.cupertino,
            appcastConfig: cfg,
            debugLogging: true,
            showLater: false,
            showIgnore: false,
            minAppVersion: '120.0.0',
            child: Container(width: 0, height: 0)),
      );
```

Debug:

```
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: build UpgradeAlert
I/flutter ( 8444): FormatException: Cannot parse empty string into version
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: blocked: false
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: debugDisplayAlways: false
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: debugDisplayOnce: false
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: hasAlerted: false
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: appStoreVersion: null
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: installedVersion: null
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: minAppVersion: 120.0.0
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: isUpdateAvailable: false
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: shouldDisplayUpgrade: false
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: appcast item count: 4
I/flutter ( 8444): upgrader: appcast best item version: 200.0.0
```

pubspec:

```
version: 110.00.05+5
```

Comment: I doubt your appcast file is accessible. Kindly check that xml file is not in a private repo.

Answer (score 2):

When I tested with your code and appcastURL, I can see the update popup.
I just added 'ios' to supportedOS parameter because I tested with iPhone simulator.

[image]

And here is a my full log when app is started.

```
flutter: upgrader: package info packageName: com.example.stackoverflow
flutter: upgrader: package info appName: null
flutter: upgrader: package info version: 110.00.05
flutter: upgrader: appcast is available for this platform
flutter: upgrader: appcast item count: 4
flutter: upgrader: appcast best item version: 200.0.0
flutter: upgrader: blocked: true
flutter: upgrader: debugDisplayAlways: false
flutter: upgrader: debugDisplayOnce: false
flutter: upgrader: hasAlerted: false
flutter: upgrader: appStoreVersion: 200.0.0
flutter: upgrader: installedVersion: 110.00.05
flutter: upgrader: minAppVersion: 120.0.0
flutter: upgrader: isUpdateAvailable: true
flutter: upgrader: shouldDisplayUpgrade: true
flutter: upgrader: showDialog title: Update App?
flutter: upgrader: showDialog message: A new version of  is available! Version 200.0.0 is now available-you have 110.00.05.
```

It seems that 'package_info' package can not get 'versionName'.
https://github.com/larryaasen/upgrader/blob/6f5827cd4feb3d13685ea4b2baa0911589876ab8/lib/src/upgrader.dart#L152

```
FormatException: Cannot parse empty string into version
```

Would you check flutterVersionName in 'android/app/build.gradle' file?
My code is below.

```
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
```

If it is same with my code, please do below steps.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

And there is a 'local.properties' file generated in '/android'.
Please check 'flutter.versionName' value in that file.

Comment: I'm not able to return the same result with my android emulator.

Comment: In my project, it works with ios, android simulator. It seems that there is a problem in platform versionName. I added comment at main comment.

Comment: We have the same code in build.gradle and I have executed the commands but nothing changed.

Comment: How about 'android/local.properties' file's contents?

Comment: `flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=110.00.05
flutter.versionCode=5`

Comment: Hm... it's interesting.. and weired. Can you share 'android/app/build.gradle' to me? turlvo@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The appCastUrl ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeejaykim/apispa/jeejaykim-test/test.xml') points to a page thats 404 (not found).

[image]

Try this instead:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/larryaasen/upgrader/master/test/testappcast.xml

Alternatively, you can create your own raw github user content using Appcast Sample File on the package docs page (on pub.dev). Using the format:

raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo-name/branch-name/path

Comment: I have a question about appcast, what is its use, if after each upgrade of my app I still have to go and update appcast?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the problem with appcast. I'm yet to find a better approach to this. If you do fine one please do share with me